# SharePoint 2016 User Profile Active Directory Import

Tags: user-profile-service, 2016, user-profile-property, adfs, claims

In our SP2016 farm,we have configured User profile service with Active Directory Import. We are using ADFS claims for authentication. While mapping AD attributes to User Properties, I'm not sure which attribute has to be mapped for "Claim Provider Type".

[image]

Actually,I configured User property mapping with reference from our SP2013 farm.In our SP2013 farm,"Claim Provider Type" is mapped as "Trusted" and if I do the same for SP2016,Active Directory Import connection gets broken.

Can someone help me what should be the AD attribute for "Claim Provider Type" in SP2016 user profile service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After selecting "User SharePoint Active Directory Import",I created a new "User Profile Synchronization Connection" and then I ran the below script to map User Profile properties and then ran a Full User Profile Synchronization:

```
$site = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite "http://CentralAdminURL"
$context = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPServiceContext]::GetContext($site)  
$configManager = New-Object 
Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileConfigManager $context  
$UPAConnMgr = $configManager.ConnectionManager  
$Connection = ($UPAConnMgr | select -First 1)  
if ($Connection.Type -eq "ActiveDirectoryImport"){ 
$Connection.AddPropertyMapping("mail","WorkEmail")
$Connection.AddPropertyMapping("userPrincipalName","SPS-UserPrincipalName")
$Connection.AddPropertyMapping("objectSid","SID")
$Connection.AddPropertyMapping("givenName","FirstName")
$Connection.AddPropertyMapping("msDS-PhoneticFirstName","SPS-PhoneticFirstName")
$Connection.AddPropertyMapping("sn","LastName")
$Connection.AddPropertyMapping("msDS-PhoneticLastName","SPS-PhoneticLastName")
$Connection.AddPropertyMapping("displayName","PreferredName")
$Connection.AddPropertyMapping("msDS-PhoneticDisplayName","SPS-PhoneticDisplayName")
$Connection.AddPropertyMapping("telephoneNumber","WorkPhone")
$Connection.AddPropertyMapping("title","SPS-JobTitle")
$Connection.AddPropertyMapping("department","Department")
$Connection.AddPropertyMapping("title","Title")
$Connection.AddPropertyMapping("department","SPS-Department")
$Connection.AddPropertyMapping("sAMAccountName","UserName")
$Connection.AddPropertyMapping("wWWHomePage","PublicSiteRedirect")
$Connection.AddPropertyMapping("proxyAddresses","SPS-SipAddress")
$Connection.AddPropertyMapping("mail","SPS-ClaimID")
$Connection.AddPropertyMapping("dn","SPS-DistinguishedName")
$Connection.AddPropertyMapping("msDS-SourceObjectDN","SPS-SourceObjectDN")
$Connection.AddPropertyMapping("physicalDeliveryOfficeName","Office")
$Connection.AddPropertyMapping("manager","Manager")
$Connection.Update()  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you configure the ADI with ADFS then Claim Provider Identifier and Claim Provider Type are set automatically, you dont need to manually set it. you just have to map the "Claim user identifier"  property as "mail".

Are you seeing any issue without mapping?

Comment: Yes, Claim Provider Identifier and Claim Provider Type are not set automatically. Active Directory Import job is running successfully but AD data is not getting imported

Comment: @George  I am curious if you guys made any inroads ? :)  Getting exception "Claim Authentication Provider Type and Claim ID must be specified together."

Comment: @FalakMahmood Apologies for the late reply. As updated by Waqas, I mapped only "Claim User Identifier"  as "mail" and then ran a full user profile sync, this fixed the issue for me.

Comment: @George if it solved the issue, could you please mark it as answer then it will be clear for others.

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMVP Done :)